# First 30 % displayed columns in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

First of all: 30% doesn't matter. That's a question of design. We can also say the first 3 Displayed Columns.

In my `DataGridView` I am using `BackgroundColors` for `Rows` to pass the User some information.

To keep this information visible to the user while Rows are being selected the first 30% of the columns should get the same `SelectionBack/ForeColor` as the `Back/ForeColor`.

So far that has never been a problem using

- `.cells(0).Style.SelectionBackColor = .cells(0).Style.Backcolor`
- (and so on).

Now I added the function that allows the user to reorder the Columns which makes the following Statement become true:

- `ColumnIndex != DisplayedIndex`.

That statement beeing true makes the SelectionBackColor-Changed cells be somewhere mixed in the row and not in the first columns anymore. It still does the job, but looks terrible.

Is there something like a "DisplayedColumns" collection in order of the `.DisplayedIndex` Value that i could use to call the first few DisplayedColumns? If not, how could I effectivly create one my own?

---

Edit:

The user can also hide specific columns, that do not matter for him. So we have to be aware of `Column.DisplayedIndex` and `Column.Visble`

---

Got it working with the following code:

```
Try
 ' calculate what is thirty percent
 Dim colcount As Integer = oDic_TabToGridview(TabPage).DisplayedColumnCount(False)
 Dim thirtyPercent As Integer = ((colcount / 100) * 30)
 ' Recolor the first 30 % of the Columns
 Dim i As Integer = 0
 Dim lastCol As DataGridViewColumn = oDic_TabToGridview(TabPage).Columns.GetFirstColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)
 While i < thirtyPercent
   .Cells(lastCol.Index).Style.SelectionBackColor = oCol(row.Item("Color_ID") - 1)
   .Cells(lastCol.Index).Style.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black
   lastCol = oDic_TabToGridview(TabPage).Columns.GetNextColumn(lastCol, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible, DataGridViewElementStates.None)
   i += 1
 End While
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox(ex.Message & vbNewLine & ex.StackTrace)
End Try
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first assume you are coloring your rows somehow resembling the following manner:

```
Me.dataGridView1.Rows(0).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PowderBlue
Me.dataGridView1.Rows(1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink
' ...etc.
```

In the `DataGridView.CellPainting` event handler, you can determine if the painting cell falls within the first `N` columns by utilizing the [DataGridViewColumnCollection.GetFirstColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.getfirstcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DataGridViewColumnCollection.GetNextColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.getnextcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

If the cell belongs to one these columns, set the cell's `SelectionBackColor` to the cell's `BackColor`.  Otherwise set it to the default highlighting color.

```
Dim column As DataGridViewColumn = Me.dataGridView1.Columns.GetFirstColumn(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)
e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromName("Highlight")

' Example: Loop for the first N displayed columns, where here N = 2.
While column.DisplayIndex < 2
    If column.Index = e.ColumnIndex Then
        e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = e.CellStyle.BackColor
        Exit While
    End If

    column = Me.dataGridView1.Columns.GetNextColumn(column, DataGridViewElementStates.Visible, DataGridViewElementStates.None)
End While
```

[image: Example GIF reording columns but first 2 remain row colored]

As a side note: You may want to consider changing the `ForeColor` on these cells for readability - depending on your row's `BackColor` choices. Likewise, if only a single cell is selected from one these first `N` columns, it can be difficult to notice.

Comment: Pretty much the best Answer I've ever got on this platform! The Keyword that helped me out was `DataGridView.Columns.GetNextColumn(...)`. I did not know this function but I am sure it will be very helpful in future projects. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! I found it very interesting to research.